# Solver Issue No Algorithm Found

Tags: python, sympy, solver

Trying to replace the function U2(x,y,z) with specified values of x,y,z. Not sure how to do that with sympy because they are as "x = arange.(-h,h,0.001)" as seen in the code below.
Below you will find my implementation with sympy. Additionally I am using PyCharm.

This implementation is based on Dr. Annabestani and Dr. Naghavis' paper: A 3D analytical ion transport model for ionic polymer metal composite actuators in large bending deformations

```
import sympy as sp
h = 0.1  # [mm] half of thickness
W: float = 6  # [mm] width
L: float = 28  # [mm] length
F: float = 96458  # [C/mol] Faraday's constant
k_e = 1.34E-6  # [F/m]
Y = 5.71E8  # [Pa]
d = 1.03 - 11  # [m^2/s] diffiusitivity coefficient
T = 293  # [K]
C_minus = 1200  # [mol/m^3] Cation concentration
C_plus = 1200 # [mol/m^3] anion concentration
R = 8.3143  # [J/mol*K] Gas constant
Vol = 2*h*W*L
#dVol = diff(Vol,x) + diff(Vol, y) + diff(Vol, z)  # change in Volume
theta = 1 / W
x, y, z, m, n, p, t = sp.symbols('x y z m n p t')
V_1 = 0.5 * sp.sin(2 * sp.pi * t)  # Voltage as a function of time
k_f = 0.5
t_f = 44
k_g = 4.5
t_g = 0.07
B_mnp = 0.003
b_mnp: float = B_mnp
gamma_hat_2 = 0.04
gamma_hat_5 = 0.03
gamma_hat_6 = 5E-3
r_M = 0.15  # membrane resistance
r_ew = 0.175  # transverse resistance of electrode
r_el = 0.11  # longitudinal resistance of electrode
mu = 2.4
sigma_not = 0.1
a_L: float = 1.0  # distrubuted surface attentuation
r_hat = sp.sqrt(r_M ** 2 + r_ew ** 2 + r_el ** 2)
lambda_1 = 0.0001
dVol = 1
K = (F ** 2 * C_minus * d * (1 - C_minus * dVol)) / (R * T * k_e)  # also K = a
K_hat = (K-lambda_1)/d
gamma_1 = 1.0
gamma_2 = 1.0
gamma_3 = 1.0
gamma_4 = 1.0
gamma_5 = 1.0
gamma_6 = 1.0
gamma_7 = 1.0
small_gamma_1 = 1.0
small_gamma_2 = 1.0
small_gamma_3 = 1.0

psi = gamma_1*x + gamma_2*y + gamma_3*z + gamma_4*x*y + gamma_5*x*z + gamma_6*y*z + gamma_7*x*y*z + (small_gamma_1/2)*x**2 + (small_gamma_2/2)*y**2 + (small_gamma_3/2)*x*z**2

psi_hat_part = ((sp.sin(((m + 1) * sp.pi) / 2 * h)) * x) * ((sp.sin(((n + 1) * sp.pi) / W)) * y) * ((sp.sin(((p + 1) * sp.pi) / L)) * z)

psi_hat = psi * psi_hat_part  # Eqn. 19
print(psi_hat)

x1: float = -h
x2: float = h
y1: float = 0
y2: float = W
z1: float = 0
z2: float = L

I = psi_hat.integrate((x, x1, x2), (y, y1, y2), (z, z1, z2))  # Integration for a_mnp Eqn. 18

A_mnp = ((8 * K_hat) / (2 * h * W * L)) * I
Partial = A_mnp * ((sp.sin(((m + 1) * sp.pi) / 2 * h)) * x) * ((sp.sin(((n + 1) * sp.pi) / W)) * y) * ((sp.sin(((p + 1) * sp.pi) / L)) * z)
start = Partial.integrate((p, 0 , 10E9), (n, 0, 10E9), (m, 0, 10E9)) #when using infinity it goes weird, also integrating leads to higher thresholds than summation


a_mnp_denom = (((sp.sin(((m + 1) * sp.pi) / 2 * h)) ** 2) * ((sp.sin(((n + 1) * sp.pi) / W)) ** 2) * (
            (sp.sin(((p + 1) * sp.pi) / L)) ** 2) + K_hat)
a_mnp = A_mnp / a_mnp_denom  # Eqn. 18
U2 = sp.Function("U2")


U2 = a_mnp * ((sp.sin(((m + 1) * sp.pi) / 2 * h)) * x) * ((sp.sin(((n + 1) * sp.pi) / W)) * y) * (
            (sp.sin(((p + 1) * sp.pi) / L)) * z)  # Eqn. 13

x = np.arange(-h, h, 0.001)
y = np.arange(-h, h, 0.001)
z = np.arange(-h, h, 0.001)
f= sp.subs((U2), (x ,y ,z))
```

I currently get the error message: ValueError: subs accepts either 1 or 2 arguments. So that means I can't use the subs() method and replace() also doesn't work too well. Are there any other methods one can use?

Any help will be grateful, thank you!

Comment: The code shown gives a different error from the one that you describe.

Comment: The code shown now gives a different error and that error is still different from the one described in the question. I suggest breaking the problem down and trying simpler examples until you are confident with the basics of using SymPy. Here your problem is just how to use `subs` which is not that difficult if you focus on small examples and carefully check the input and output. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Oscar is right: you are trying to deal with too much of the problem at once. That aside, Numpy and SymPy do not work like you think they do. What were you hoping to see when you replaced 3 variables, each with a range?

You cannot replace a SymPy variable/Symbol with a Numpy `arange` object, but you can replace a Symbol with a single value:

```py
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> a = 1.0
>>> u = x + y + a
>>> u.subs(x, 1)
y + 2.0
>>> u.subs([(x,1), (y,2)])
4.0
```

You might iterate over the `arange` values, creating values of `f` and then doing something with each value:

```py
f = lambda v: u.subs(dict(zip((x,y),v))) 
for xi in range(1,3): # replace range with your arange call
  for yi in range(-4,-2):
    fi = f((xi,yi))
    print(xi,yi,fi)
```

Be careful about iterating and using `x` or `y` as your loop variable, however, since that will then lose the assignment of the Symbol to that variable,

```py
for x in range(2):
  print(u.subs(x, x)) # no change and x is no longer a Symbol, it is now an int
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers. Yes I am relatively new to creating my own code from scratch. So thank you for the explainations. 
I guess it's not possible to iterate with 3 variables with the `dict(zip())` function. I'm not sure how to store the values of `f((xi,yi))` to manipulate them in another for loop to evaluate for `z` values.

Comment: That `dict(zip(a, b))` will work with `a` and `b` of any length. If they are not the same length, however, the extras will be ignored.